# Python count number of keys in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I made a nested dictionary of my file to group events in classes. I wanted to count by key numbers how many of classes to I have and how many final values there are. this is the code I have so far:

```
infile = open('ALL','r')

def round_down(num):
    return num - (num%100)

count = 0
a = []
split_region = {}
lengths = []
for region in infile:
    #print region

    (cov,chrm,pos,end,leng) = region.split()
    start = int(pos)#-1#-int(leng) ## loosen conditions about break points
    end = int(end)
    lengths = int(leng)
    coverage=int(cov)
    rounded_start=round_down(start)
    rounded_length=round_down(lengths)
    if not (chrm in split_region):
        split_region[chrm]={}
    if not (rounded_start in split_region[chrm]):
        split_region[chrm][rounded_start]={}
    if not (rounded_length in split_region[chrm][rounded_start]):
        split_region[chrm][rounded_start][rounded_length]= []
    split_region[chrm][rounded_start][rounded_length].append({'start':start,'length':lengths,'cov':coverage})

    for k,v in split_region[chrm][rounded_start].items():
        print len(v),k,v
        a.append(len(v))
        count +=1
print count
print sum(a)
```

file is formatted like this:

```
5732    chrM    1   16572   16571
804 chr6    58773612    58780166    6554
722 chr1    142535435   142538993   3558
448 chrY    13447747    13451695    3948
372 chr9    68422753    68423813    1060
327 chr2    133017433   133018716   1283
302 chr18   107858  109884  2026
256 chr20   29638813    29641416    2603
206 chr6    57423087    57429121    6034
204 chr1    142537237   142538991   1754
```

So it basically works by rounding down the numbers by 100 and making a class out of it in my dictionary. It's nested since first I group by rounded start and then rounded length variables.

At the end of the code I try to count how many of the classes there are, and what is total count of my values. This however gives incorrect output: more classes than lines in input file. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: create a *small* test file, and do some debugging/tracing.

Comment: I don't know how big your input file is, but I guess that in your `for` loop at the bottom, you might count items twice, which makes the counter go up incorrectly.

Comment: yep. However when I move the last for loop outside the top one, i get correct number for keys only at the top level of dictionary. Any step further and everything gets messed up.

Comment: And that's the solution. If the loop is inside the top one, you count the first item `n` times, the second item `n-1` times etc. where `n` is the number of lines in your file. If something else "gets messed up" then I suggest you describe this as a problem. Because the current question is trivial.

Comment: Well if it's trivial, then where is the solution? Moving for loop outside the top one doesn't solve the problem of counting number of keys at each level of the nested dictionary

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me which total count you want, but maybe one of the following is what you are looking for:

```
rounded_start_count = 0
rounded_length_count = 0
rounded_length_value_count = 0

for k1, v1 in split_region.items():
    print k1 + ": " + str(len(v1))
    rounded_start_count += len(v1)
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        rounded_length_count += len(v2)
        rounded_length_value_count += len(v2.values())

print ""

print "chrm count:                 ", len(split_region.keys())
print "Rounded start count:        ", rounded_start_count
print "Rounded length count:       ", rounded_length_count
print "Rounded length value count: ", rounded_length_count
```

This would be placed after and outside your for loop. This prints the following output for your sample data:

> ```
> chr6: 2
> chr2: 1
> chr1: 2
> chr9: 1
> chrY: 1
> chr20: 1
> chrM: 1
> chr18: 1
>
> chrm count:                  8
> Rounded start count:         10
> Rounded length count:        10
> Rounded length value count:  10
> ```